# SQL query language

Tags: sql

I'll try to keep this neat as I have a few questions.

First, given this entity

```
play(movie, scene, actor)
```

I would like to find the names of actors who played in movies in which angelina jolie is playing. would this work

```
SELECT 
    p.actor
FROM 
    play p
WHERE 
    p.actor NOT LIKE 'Angelina Jolie'
    AND p.movie IN (SELECT p.movie
                    FROM play p
                    WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie');
```

Second question: I would like to print the names of the actors who only play in movies in which angelina jolie is playing. Would this work

```
SELECT 
    p.actor
FROM 
    play p
WHERE 
    p.actor NOT LIKE 'Angelina Jolie'
    AND p.movie = ALL(SELECT p.movie
                      FROM play p
                      WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie');
```

Now lastly, for another question, given the following entities

```
airline (name, telephone, designator)
flight (name, number, departure, arrival, origin, destination)
airport (name, country, designator)
```

I would like to print the pairs of names of competing airline. Airlines with the same route or having the same origin and destination. Removing the symmetry from the result as an airline does not compete with itself. Would this work

```
SELECT 
    a1.name, a2.name
FROM 
    airline a1, airline a2, flight f1, flight f2
WHERE 
    a1.name <> a2.name
    AND a1.name = f1.name
    AND a2.name = f2.name
    AND f1.origin = f2.origin
    AND f1.destination = f2.destination
GROUP BY 
    a1.name, a2.name;
```

Then, print the names of the airlines that have flights to all listed airports in thailand.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.name
FROM 
    airline a, flight f
WHERE 
    f.destination = ALL(SELECT a.name
                        FROM airport a
                        WHERE a.country = 'Thailand');
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Agreed! One minor note, old style joins are still in the ANSI SQL standard.(Backward compatibility.)

Comment: Duplicated question is answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793771/sql-language-query/28794494