# SQL language query

Tags: sql

First, given this table

```
CREATE TABLE play(
movie VARCHAR(256), 
scene VARCHAR(256),
actor VARCHAR(256));
```

I would like to find the names of actors who played in movies in which angelina jolie is playing. would this work

```
SELECT p.actor
FROM play p
WHERE 
p.actor NOT LIKE 'Angelina Jolie'
AND p.movie IN (SELECT p.movie
                FROM play p
                WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie');
```

Second question: I would like to print the names of the actors who only play in movies in which angelina jolie is playing. Would this work

```
SELECT p.actor
FROM play p
WHERE 
p.actor NOT LIKE 'Angelina Jolie'
AND p.movie = ALL(SELECT p.movie
                  FROM play p
                  WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie');
```

Comment: Have you tried? BTW, you can use <> instead of NOT LIKE. (Since no wildcards are involved, LIKE is not needed.)

Comment: `"Would this work"` - Your database engine is going to be able to tell you that far more effectively than we would.  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for just executing the code.

Comment: The second will not work because one value cannot be equal to everything in a set of values.  It is a shame that you are learning the `ALL`, `SOME`, and `ANY` keywords.  I think there are better ways to express such queries.

Comment: Either I'm looking at this wrong or your query doesn't make much sense. 
You're looking for movies where the actor is NOT Angelina Jolie but then you want all films where Angelina Jolie is acting in it? This won't work.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Above query will  work, although there is better way to do it

Comment: You're right @ubaid I was looking at it wrong.

Comment: But, his table structure is very poorly formulated, If he needs to keep record of actors in a movie , movie column is duplicated every time.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779233/sql-query-language

Answer (score 0):

Your first query will work, not the second.

This instead will work:

```
     SELECT distinct actor
    FROM play p
    WHERE p.actor <> 'Angelina Jolie'
    and movie in (SELECT p.movie
                      FROM play p
                      WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie')
     and actor not in 
    -- actors in movies without Jolie
    (SELECT p.actor
    FROM play p
    WHERE  movie in
    (select distinct movie
    from play
    where movie not in(
    select p.movie
    from play p
    WHERE p.actor = 'Angelina Jolie')
    ))
```